# Automatically Updating C# Programs

Tags: c#, winforms

What do I have to add to a C# program in order for it to search for and update itself every time it loads up?

Comment: What kind of application is this? are you trying to make it a Click-Once App?

Comment: A lot of ways to do it. One way is check for updates, start an updater program and exit your app. MS also has some libraries, I think called BITS.

Comment: I'm curious if there's examples that don't rely on click-once. Click-Once is an excellent platform, but it's kind of limited in ways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out Click Once:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something that's hard or impossible with ClickOnce (which includes most non-trivial tasks), check out [AppLife Update](http://www.kineticjump.com/).

Comment: I am curious as to why this answer has downvotes. Perhaps the downvoters could leave a comment.

Comment: +1  We use AppLife, and I love it.  There are things to like about ClickOnce, but it is very limited.

Comment: I'd like to know this, too. Sure, it's commercial, but it easily saves the money it costs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a .NET application updater component from Microsoft that comes with the source code:

http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx

I have used this on several projects and it works well.